# Error on Yum update

Tags: centos, yum

I'm unfortunately not very experienced in CentOS administration, and was hoping someone might be able to help me understand and get past a small hurdle.  I was hoping to run yum update on the system, but ran into some Transaction Check Errors:

```
file /etc/php.ini from install of php55-common-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so from install of php55-common-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php55-common-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so from install of php55-common-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so from install of php55-pdo-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so from install of php55-pdo-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so from install of php55-pdo-5.5.11-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

It sort of looks like it's saying that some newer version files are conflicting with older version files.  Is there a standard way to fix this?  I was mainly just trying to update so that I could install Java later, but wasn't expecting to run into these errors.  If it helps, the server is mainly being used for hosting a few websites with apache and mysql.  Thanks so much for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:  To add some more clarification, I had previously edited the baseurl variable in the **/etc/yum.repos.d/centalt.repo** file, which was originally set to

```
baseurl=centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/$basearch
```

The reason I changed the location was because I was previously getting an error when trying to run yum update, mentioned in this other stackoverflow question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132674/repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-repository-mratwork-centalt which had an answer recommending replacing the URL with

```
baseurl=mirror.sysadminguide.net/centalt/repository/centos/6/$basearch
```

Is there a different url I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non-official repository which provides the `php55-*` packages which conflict with the official `php-*` packages.

You currently have the `php-*` versions installed.

If you want to switch you can try manually installing the matching `php55-*` package for every `php-*` package you have installed in one `yum` command (though that may not work).

If it doesn't, you might need to remove all the php packages you have installed first and then install the php55 versions after that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Maybe it has to do with me changing the baseurl variable in the /etc/yum.repos.d/centalt.repo file.  It was originally set to baseurl=http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/$basearch/, but I had been previously been getting an error mentioned in this other stackoverflow question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132674/repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-repository-mratwork-centalt which had an answer recommending replacing the URL with baseurl=http://mirror.sysadminguide.net/centalt/repository/centos/6/$basearch/.  Is there a different url I should use instead?

Comment: Changing the baseurl, assuming you keep pointing at a similar repository, should only change where you get the packages from not what packages you get. And I can't suggest a specific mirror but, in general, I think using a mirror list is better than using a specific host (unless you know the specific host and have a reason to prefer it).

Comment: Oh, does that mean the new baseurl I changed to might be providing php55-* packages instead of the php-* packages for some reason?  If so, is there a way then for me to find an alternative similar url for the baseurl=centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/$basearch?  I guess I just wanted to do a normal update if possible, several sites I visited seemed to recommend that new baseurl I mentioned before, but I'm not really certain about it.

Comment: I have no idea, offhand, what packages `centos.alt.ru` held or what the mirrors listed by `mirrors.sysadminguide.net` contain. You might have accidentally switched package providers. I don't know. Where did you get `centos.alt.ru` from in the first place?

Comment: Ah, I think I'm getting a clearer picture of the overall problem.  TBH I'm not too sure how the centos.alt.ru url got set in the first place, I think my hosting provider may have set it to that initially.  I think I'll want to get in contact with them about it, I appreciate all the helpful input you've given so far it's much appreciated.